# Why does it print an ASCII character if I use an int, but not if I use a variable?

Tags: java

The following code prints `A` to the console:

```java
char ch = (char)65.25;

System.out.println(ch);
```

However I don't understand why the next piece of code doesn't print the ASCII character?

```java
int rand = (int)currentSeconds % 26;

System.out.println(" the number is " + rand);

char randN = (char)rand;

System.out.println(randN);
```

Below follows the full code:

```java
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println(" using current second to  generate random Uppercase letter");

long totalsecs = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
long currentSeconds = totalsecs % 60;
long totalMinute = totalsecs/60;
long currentMinute = totalMinute%60;
long totalHours = totalMinute/60;
long currentHours = totalHours%24;

System.out.println("current time is " +currentHours +":"+ currentMinute +":"+currentSeconds);


int rand = (int)currentSeconds % 26;
System.out.println(" the number is " + rand);
char randN = (char)rand;

System.out.println(randN);
```

Comment: What ascii characters do you think are in the range `0` to `26`? Basically, what part of this is confusing and why?

Comment: omg you helped me solve it. the task was to print a random upper case character using the current second. I just need to add 65. For example if the time is 12:20:00 as in zero seconds, i then add 65 to it to make the decimal number 65 then convert that to char and it prints "A"

Comment: Try `'A' + rand;` (I would prefer the `char` constant to the ascii magic number).

Comment: im only up to chapter 2 of introduction to java programming by Y. Daniel Liang. and it hasn't taught me about the rand method yet. however thanks for that i will keep that in mind!

Comment: `rand` is your `int` in this case. `char randN = (char) ('A' + rand);`

Answer (score 3):

There are many versions of the `println` method, with different parameter types.  In other words, if `s` is a `String`, `i` is an `int` and `c` is a `char`, then `System.out.println(i)` is actually calling a different method from `System.out.println(c)`, which is calling a different method from `System.out.println(s)`.  It's the compiler's job to figure out which method you're trying to call, and it takes into account the type of the expression that you pass in.  So

- `System.out.println(rand)` calls the `int` version of the method, which prints the number.
- `System.out.println(randN)` calls the `char` version of the method, which prints the character, rather than its numeric equivalent.
- `System.out.println("the number is " + rand)` calls the `String` version of the method, which prints a `String`, and in this case, the `String` is made by concatenating the number to the end of a `String` literal.

If you're trying to print a character value in the range `A` to `Z` in place of a number from 0 to 25, then writing `char randN = (char) rand;` isn't enough - that won't actually convert the number to the range you want, because the numeric values of the characters from `A` to `Z` are not actually 0 to 25.

You need to write `char randN = 'A' + rand;` to effect the desired conversion.

Answer (score -1):

## tl;dr

```
Character.toString
( 
    "A".codePointAt( 0 ) 
    +
    ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 0 , 27 )
)
```

Or:

```
Character.toString
( 
    ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 65 , ( 65 + 27 ) )
)
```

## Start with `A`

As others pointed out, to get a random character from A-Z, you need to add 0-25 to a starting number, that number being the code for `A` which is 65.

## Avoid `char`

Another problem with your code is its use of the `char`. The `char` type in Java is legacy, essentially broken. As a 16-bit value, that type cannot represent most characters.

While your particular case of A-Z works with `char`, using `char` is a bad habit, and an unnecessary habit.

## Code points

Instead learn to use Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers. Unicode is a superset of US-ASCII, so code points 0-127 represent the same characters in both.

```
int codePointForA = "A".codePointAt( 0 ) ;  // 65
int addend = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 0 , 27 ) ;  // ( inclusive , exclusive )
int randomCodePoint = ( codePointForA + addend ) ;
String randomCharacter = Character.toString( randomCodePoint ) ;
```

See [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/LXurzy).

> Z